# Retrieving external content. Load dynamic with jquery into iframe without browser lag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm create and loading multiple iframes with basic src. But, I have noticed that for each now iframes I create and the src being added with new url for each, the browers locks a bit. So I thought, can I add the page though Ajax instead, using php proxy on the server. I have managed to do this in some extent, but all data does not load. For example, in one specific case a flexslider does not load.
I use

PHP Using phpQuery:

```
     $html = file_get_contents('http://' . $myitem['Web_address']);     
        $doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
        $doc->find('head')->prepend('<base href="'.'http://' . $myitem['Web_address'].'">');
```

JQUERY: (Note, the iframe is already prepaired with a loader.html document)

```
    $('iframe').contents().find('html').html(data.comp[0]['html']);
```

A lot does load, but some images do not, can I load ALL content, and how can I acheive this.

Thanks!